# I want to write a code, which hyperlinks a shape to another sheet in workbook AND records on background if the shape is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel and I created a shape, which once clicked, redirects the user to a specific cell on another worksheet. So far so good. I did this with no code, just right click, then "hyperlink", etc... However, I also need to record whether the shape has been clicked or not on a third worksheet, once the user has been redirected. A simple "TRUE" or "YES" output in a table will do. Unfortunately, clicking on the shape has to result in both actions (redirecting the user and entering value in the table), and I don't know how to do that. Please help.

I know that a macro can be assigned to the shape, but when I recorded one, which added the value "TRUE" in a table, and added it to the shape, only the manually entered hyperlink worked, the user was redirected on click, but the value "TRUE" did not appear in the cell I set it to (is on another worksheet, different from the one, where the shape is located, or where the user gets redirected).

Comment: Not sure I follow everything you wrote there, but every shape that needs to be clickable needs to be assigned to a macro.

Comment: Not sure if this works on hyperlinked shapes, but you can try using the `worksheet_followhyperlink` event